# Setting local properties in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

How does one set a local property in Android Studio projects?  I'd like to set a directory variable for a project that obviously could be different for each user of the project.  It seems like `local.properties` would be a good place for this, which could then be accessed via the top level `build.gradle` however the header of `local.properties` says

> Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
>
> This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
>   as it contains information specific to your local configuration.

Seems by the comment that this is the file to use, but then it goes on to say don't make modifications.

Comment: as far as I'm aware, this only get's erased/re-writen when you import the code into AndroidStudio. That's the moment AndroidStudio generates this file (and will override any existing file. But I might be wrong on that one and I suggest you to make a test to double check this behavior.